# Regex in C++ 11 with option R

Tags: c++, regex

I've the following statement in C++ which uses Regex:

```
if (regex_match(argv[i], regex(R"((.*)\.o)")))
```

My question now is what does the `regex(R"((.*)\.o)")"` do? I know that the outer regex_match function checks to see if the `argv[i]` is equal to the second statement separated by the comma. This evaluates to true if they are equal, and false if they aren't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`regex(XXXX)` creates a new `std::regex` object, invoking the [appropriate constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex) depending on what `XXXX` is. In this case, it's the second one from that list.

Because...

`R"(...)"` is a a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), that lets you use things like backslashes in the regular expression without having to escape them like you would in a normal string literal.

If you don't know what the regular expression itself matches, or even what regular expressions are... that's a much bigger topic and there's plenty of tutorials out there you can start with.

(Using `std::regex_search()` and a RE of `\.o$` would be a better way to write that, IMO, or an approach that doesn't use REs at all.)

Comment: Perfect thanks! What would be a way to write this without REs?

Comment: @KenB Just check to see if the string has at least two characters and that if it does the last two are `'.'` and `'o'`. (C++20 will add a `ends_with()` method to `std::string` and friends that would have been perfect for this, but that's still in the future...)